# Partition Z-Scores Across Multiple Factors in R

Tags: scales, psychometrics, z-score, partitioning

**Basic question**
Is there a way to create z-scores across multiple factors quickly? And how would you do this without creating multiple subsets and rebinding them?

**Details** 
Basically I am comparing pilot data of three scales (scale_type: VAS (0 to 100), LMS (0 to 100), TS (-18 to 18). The result of each is put into a column tabled *score*. We have two factors (colour, contrast) both of which have three levels (i.e. color can be dark, grey, white and contrast can be none, medium, bright).

```
scale_type = c("LMS","VAS","TS","LMS","VAS","TS","LMS","VAS","TS")
contrast = c("none","medium","bright","medium","bright","none","bright","medium","none")
colour = c("white","grey","dark","grey","dark","white","dark","grey","white")
scale_type <- rep(scale_type, 3)
contrast <- rep(contrast, 3)
colour <- rep(colour, 3)
score <- runif(27, min=0, max=100)

satis <- data.frame(scale_type,contrast,colour,score)
satis
   scale_type contrast colour     score
1         LMS     none  white 16.639378
2         VAS     dull   grey 90.042460
3          TS   bright   dark 13.407820
4         LMS     dull   grey 13.161413
5         VAS   bright   dark 10.528750
6          TS     none  white 51.158358
7         LMS   bright   dark 30.019905
8         VAS     dull   grey  2.671690
9          TS     none  white 30.964743
10        LMS     none  white 74.211966
11        VAS     dull   grey  3.545673
12         TS   bright   dark 56.507611
13        LMS     dull   grey 28.025778
14        VAS   bright   dark 20.419632
15         TS     none  white 13.373890
16        LMS   bright   dark 32.568192
17        VAS     dull   grey 15.506197
18         TS     none  white 12.996214
19        LMS     none  white 43.553106
20        VAS     dull   grey  3.864265
21         TS   bright   dark 71.330156
22        LMS     dull   grey 10.076904
23        VAS   bright   dark 95.030494
24         TS     none  white 12.181776
25        LMS   bright   dark 21.965662
26        VAS     dull   grey 91.308777
27         TS     none  white 94.585312
```

The ANOVA from the data would look like this...

```
satis.aov <- aov(score ~ colour * contrast * scale_type, data=satis)
summary(satis.aov)
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
colour             2    634   317.1   0.277  0.761
scale_type         2    551   275.4   0.241  0.788
colour:scale_type  2    788   393.9   0.345  0.713
Residuals         20  22863  1143.1
```

Due to differences in the scales, I need to normalise the data into z-scores, which account for each level. What is the fastest method to do this?

Comment: By z-score do you mean that you want to remove the mean and then scale by the standard deviation for each of the three scales separately?

Comment: @bluepole Basically I want to compare the three factors (scale_type, contrast, and colour) with z-scores in order to look for differences in performance. I was under the impression that I needed to partition the z-scores within each condition, creating a scores for each i.e. LMS none and dark; LMS, none and white etc. Would this be the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: Since you're looking for the differences in performance across the three scales, it does not make sense to normalize the original values to z-scores because the normalization would negate your original analysis purpose. Maybe you should try to bring the three scales to some common scale without losing the data integrity so that you would still be able to meaningfully compare the three scales.